# Docker environment is not running VueJs component in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, docker, vue.js

I have docker containers for my laravel environment but my vuejs component is not displaying . I have connection refused error when it comes to my app.js.
Connection refused `http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js`

My laravel project is running on localhost:9000 in my root directory I have placed an htaccess that will bypass the url from displaying "public/" in the url and when I run my npm run dev in my laravel container the npm is running on localhost:5173. This is my setup I have run clear npm cache etc but my vuejs example is not showing.

Docker file

```
FROM php:8.1.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Mod Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev 

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
# install curl 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:

  laravel-docker:
    container_name: laravel-docker
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./booking-app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:80
  
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bootstrap_db
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

  npm:
    image: node:current-alpine
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./booking-app:/var/www/html
    user: node
    entrypoint: ["npm"]
    working_dir: /var/www/html
```

**My Vue App.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import Example from './components/Example.vue';
const app = createApp({
    components:{
        Example,
    }
});

app.mount("#app");
```

**Components Folder/Example.vue**

```
<script setup>
</script>
<template>
<h1>My Example</h1>
</template>
```

**My laravel blade template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Booking Welcome</title>
    @vite(['./resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app">
            <Example />
        </div>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the browser? Please attached the container logs

Comment: You need to share how you access your app and where did you get `Connection refused` error.

Comment: If you are accessing from host machine, according to your `docker-compose.yml` there is none of container expose the 5173 port to your host might be the reason.

Comment: I have tried to expose but to no success. The error I get is
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE app.js

Comment: any idea about this solution?